# How to allow access by headers > user-agent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to allow requests from some origins or all requests if they are from a specific user-agent.

```
...
var whitelist = [URL1, URL2];
  corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || origin.req.header['user-agent'] === 'SpecificUserAgent') {
        callback(null, true)
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
      }
    }
  };
...
```

Being **origin.req.header['user-agent'] === 'SpecificUserAgent'** just a sample what I need.

Is there any way to do it? Tanks.

Comment: What's the use case for this, exactly? Sound like a bad idea. If you're going to do it anyway, don't forget to list `User-Agent` in the `Vary` response header, to avoid [cache poisoning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2RrmNxJZ5c&t=14m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own middleware on top of all the routes you'd like to protect, and parse user-agents just like you did.

However this method gives no safety at all as a user-agent can be spoofed easily.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.headers['user-agent'].match(/firefox/gi))
    return res.status(403).send({error: "Unauthorized browser"})
  
  next()
})
```